Is possible not to apply JPA EntityListener during test, but only real execution?
I'd like to apply EntityListener only during real execution, but not test. Because the EntityListener currently I use changes Entity's property on read, so it might be confusing when verifying column value.
I actually put EntityListener on submodule, and use it on main module with dependency specified and AutoConfiguration. I'd like to modify codes on submodule so that users of it doesn't have to make any configurations on main module and just use it, and there is no side-effects during testing in main module.
